# Unit test does not resolve

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Because state change (which is mocked by `getManagedEntries`) on initialise and error `"test was not wrapped in act (...)"`  placed render in act(), but now the test does not resolve.. the timers keeps on going, see screenshot.

```
it('should render without crashing', async () => {
    (getManagedEntries as jest.MockedFunction<typeof getManagedEntries>).mockImplementation(() => {
        return Promise.resolve(getManagedEntriesData) as any;
    });

    await act(async () => {
        render(<SegmentDropdown config={configForSegmentDropdown} depth={1} root={true} segment={'test'} />, {
            wrapper,
        });
    });

    waitFor(() => {
        //ignore this useless test which is for the sake of simplicity > I just needs this test to resolve
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. Show the code of the `SegmentDropdown` component

Comment: [There's no need to `act` on `render`](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#wrapping-things-in-act-unnecessarily).